# why does web server display images corrupterd?

Tags: image, jsp, tomcat

I have a page in JSP, which has a tag like:
`<img src="images/1.bmp"></img>`
The 1.bmp is like:
[image]

But the image which looks in my page, visited by firefox, is like:
[image]
what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Ugg, using .bmp files on a webpage? Consider converting them to something else (jpeg, png). What does Firebug display as the 'content-type' for this image when it's being served?

Comment: I have to use bmp files, cause of my website functionality.
How may I see the 'content-type' by means of Firebug?

Comment: In firebug, click the 'Net' tab, then reload the page. you should see a 'Get imagename.bmp', click the + sign and see, 'Headers'.

Comment: the response header is like this:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.3)

Comment: None of this is displayed in place I asked you to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've converted the images which you uploaded into your question back to BMP and investigated their source. Everywhere where a non-ISO-8859-1 character appears in the original source, a `?` appears in the malformed source.

This means that you've a servlet on `/images/*` which uses `response.getWriter()` to write the image using the platform default charset. You shouldn't do that. BMP files are not text files. BMP files are binary files. You should be using `response.getOutputStream()` to write binary data. You can find a basic and proper example of an image servlet in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html).